# withCredentials = true is not working even after using CORS

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, axios, passport-local

I am using Vue@CLI and ExpressJs , with Passport.js for authentication. I have written the following code for setting local strategy for authentication using email & password. I have tested the code in postman and it is working fine, cookies are stored successfully for the session.

But when I am fetching the Http Request from the client, i.e. VueJs then it stores the session but when I refresh the browser, the session is disappeared. I

I am just a beginner in Web Dev and I have tried every solution that was provided on internet, like using axios.defaults.withCredentials = true and passing withCredentials: true with the requests.

Please help me I am blocked....

users.js

> ```
> router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {   
>
> passport.authenticate('local', {
>     session: false
>     }, (err, user, info) => {
>         if(err) return next(err)
>         if (!user) { 
>             return res.send("LogIn Failed") 
>         }
>         req.logIn(user, function(err) {
>         if (err) { return next(err) }  
>         req.session.user = "hey"
>         console.log(req.session)
>         res.send("Log In Success")              
>
>     })
> })(req, res, next)router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {   
>
> passport.authenticate('local', {
>     session: false
>     }, (err, user, info) => {
>         if(err) return next(err)
>         if (!user) { 
>             return res.send("LogIn Failed") 
>         }
>         req.logIn(user, function(err) {
>         if (err) { return next(err) }  
>         req.session.user = "hey"
>         console.log(req.session)
>         res.send("Log In Success")              
>
>     })
> })(req, res, next)  
>  })
> ```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const morgan = require('morgan')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const session = require('express-session')
const passport = require('passport')
const cors = require('cors')
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

//Config Passport
require('./config/passport')(passport)

//Routes
const projectRoutes = require('./api/routes/projects')
const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/users')


//App Middlewares
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cookieParser())


//Express Session
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret-key',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new MongoStore({ 
      mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
       ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 
   }),
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

    }
}))

//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//Route Middlewares
app.use('/project', projectRoutes)
app.use('/user', userRoutes)

//404 Not Found
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error('Not Found')
    error.status = 404
    next(error)
})

//Errors
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500)
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    })
})

//Database Connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/database', { useNewUrlParser: true },)
    // mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;



module.exports = app
```

and I am passing the following request:

```
this.result = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login', {               
       email: this.email,
       password: this.password              
},
{withCredentials: true});
```

Comment: bro did you get the solution ? I am also having same problem

Answer (score 0):

Just change `app.use(cors())` to

```
app.use(cors(
  {origin: ['your client side server'],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  credentials:true,
}
))
```